# Seeking Efficient Enumeration Strategies for Graph Partitioning

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph-theory, combinatorics, enumeration

I am currently working on a class project that involves partitioning a non-directed graph, possibly weighted, into p classes. The objective is to minimize the sum of the weights of the edges between vertices not belonging to the same class. Additionally, it's crucial to ensure that the vertices are distributed approximately equally across the pp classes.

For my initial approach, I am focusing on the explicit enumeration ("generate and test") method to find the optimal partitioning. The project's requirements include to find the optimal solution for small graphs (25 vertices)

To approach this, I've developed a function that explicitly enumerates the entire brute search space. However, this method has proven to be less than ideal. For instance, when setting n=16 (vertices) and p=5 (classes), generating all possible partitions already takes more than 10 minutes. Given that I need to find the optimal solution for graphs up to 25 vertices, I cannot begin to imagine the time it would take for even larger instances. This has led me to conclude that before evaluating the current solution from my brute search space, I must first find a way to effectively reduce the possibilities within my search space.

How can I pre-reduce the enumeration process's search space effectively? Are there known strategies or criteria that can help eliminate non-viable partitions early on?

Here is an example of a small instance
number vertices | number of edges
5 8
min degree max degree
3 4
source destination weigth
1 2 1
1 5 1
1 3 1
2 3 1
2 4 1
2 5 1
3 4 1
4 5 1
degree of each vertices
1 3
2 4
3 3
4 3
5 3

`void generate(int n, int p) {
vector vecteur(n, 1);

```
unsigned long long int total_combinations = pow(p, n);
for (unsigned long long int i = 0; i < total_combinations; i++) {
    //printVector(vecteur);
    for (int j = n - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
        if (vecteur[j] < p) {
            vecteur[j]++;
            break;
        } else {
            vecteur[j] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

}`

Comment: "Additionally, it's crucial to ensure that the vertices are distributed approximately equally across the pp classes" - what does this mean specifically? Could you formalize this?

Comment: Your partitioning is called clustering, although typically clustering minimizes intra-distance, not inter-distance which is what you are looking for. You may want to look into network clustering

Comment: Hello,
First of all, thank you for your interest. First of all, no, I'm talking about partitioning the graph into p classes, in such a way that the sum of the weights of the edges between vertices that don't belong to the same class is minimal so that the sum of the weights of the edges between vertices not belonging to the same class is minimal, so we want to minimise the inter-class sum and not the intra-class sum. To clarify this idea of a balanced group/class, this means that we have "roughly" the same number of individuals in each class. Each group must have approximately n/p vertices.

Comment: Finally, I've improved my function by starting from a feasible solution. I think we can consider this topic resolved because I don't think it's possible to go any faster than browsing.